# R: loop returning list of plots include NULL

Tags: r, list, loops, plot, plotly

I have the following code. It selects data and makes a plotly plot. The code loops through the variable "criteria" and at the end of the loop inserts the plot in the appropriate index.

Everything works fine except that all but the last elements of the list are null and only the last plot is included.

How do I include all the plotly charts in the list?

```
criteria <- c("A", "B", "C")


for(i in 1:length(criteria)){
    plotTbl <- dataTbl[Site == criteria[i]]
    plotTbl <- unique(plotTbl[ ,N := .N, by = .(Site, Var)])

    noexacCols <- unique(c(brewer.pal(name="Set1", n = 9),
                           brewer.pal(name="Set2", n = 8),
                           brewer.pal(name="BrBG", n =11),
                           brewer.pal(name="Paired", n = 12)))

    noexacCols <- noexacCols[i]

    colMapper <- data.table(Var = sort(unique(plotTbl[,Var])))
    colMapper[, colorCodes := noexacCols]
    plotTbl <- plotTbl[colMapper, on = .(Var), nomatch = 0]

    plotTbl[ ,Percent := round(100*N/sum(N), 1)]
    plotTbl[ ,text2display := paste0("Site = ",Site,
                                     "<br>",category, " = ", Var,
                                     "<br>N = ", N, " (", Percent, "%)")]


    f1 <- list(
      family = "Arial, sans-serif",
      size = 14,
      color = "black"
    )
    f2 <- list(
      family = "Arial, sans-serif",
      size = 12,
      color = "black"
    )

    a <- list(
      title = "",
      titlefont = f1,
      showticklabels = TRUE,
      tickangle = 0,
      tickfont = f2
    )

    b <- list(
      title = "",
      titlefont = f1,
      showticklabels = TRUE,
      tickangle = 0,
      tickfont = f2,
      zeroline = TRUE,
      showline = TRUE,
      mirror = FALSE,
      linecolor = toRGB("black"),
      linewidth = 1
    )

    p <- list()
    p[[i]] <- plot_ly(data = plotTbl ,
                      x = ~Var,
                      y = ~N,
                      type = 'bar',
                      marker = list(color = ~colorCodes),
                      opacity = 0.7,
                      hoverinfo="text",
                      text = ~text2display) %>%
      layout(xaxis = a, yaxis = b, showlegend = F, margin = list(b = 30))

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create `p` within the loop and thus overwrite it on every revolution. Move line `p <- list()` before the loop.